# Package a native DLL in a UWP project - Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, dll, uwp

I have a problem with automatically build a UWP project to copy and link a non-COM native DLL properly.

Basically whenever I run the application, it cannot find the linked DLL after I build it. It will throw out `System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'es200601.dll' or one of its dependencies: The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'`
[image]

I have added the DLL files to the root project directory. Because they're not typed library, unfortunately, I cannot add them to the project as references, instead, I have to use `DllImport`. I've set the DLL files' build action as "Content" and the copy setting to "Always".

I've also tried SetDLLDirectory from kernel32 to the output path, but that doesn't work.

I've checked the output directory, and the DLL files are correctly copied to the base AppX folder, but it still gives out that error.

[image]

There is a workaround though. If I copy the DLL files to the entrypoint folder, which only contains the output exe, then it works. But it requires me to manually copy the files after compile. With that in mind, I've also tried using append `"..\\"` in the `DllImport` path, but I got access denied error this time.

I'm looking to either find a way to configure the project in Visual Studio to copy the files there or perhaps somehow use the base AppX directory to find the DLL.

Comment: Have you tried to set other target platform  such as x86 platfrom?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I've used x86 platform. Actually it's the only time the hack works when I have to copy the DLL manually to the `entrypoint` folder

Comment: that's interesting, can you try make a blank app for testing.  or clean your project (delete bin and obj folder).

Comment: @NicoZhu if I create a WPF project on Visual Studio, it would work fine. In the case of UWP project, seems that it has something to do with the `entrypoint` folder because it contains the executable there, even though the parent folder also have it. I'm not sure how to ensure that it runs the one in parent folder

Comment: I suppose entrypoint specific folder name casue this problem. can you try to updates it as a nomal one such as `point` folder.

Comment: What do you mean? As in renaming it? If I remove it then VS Code would generate it again. I still don't know how to configure it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, the DLL files are corrupted. Copying a new set of DLL files seems to fix the issue. The working case in the WPF project was a fluke because I copied a new set of DLL files from the source. After copying the same DLL file to the UWP project, all is solved.

I'm surprised that the error message for both the DLL file is missing and it's corrupted are one and the same, which confused me earlier as the problem it's a matter of path resolution.