# VS2022 Set Up Dependency on Native DLL for UWP App

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2022

I have a UWP app in the works that depends on a native DLL.  These are all under my control and in the same Solution.

If I try to add a Project Reference to the UWP app referencing the native DLL project, the resulting error message states: "A reference to MyNativeDLL could not be added.  The method or operation is not implemented."

The P/Invoke work is already done and functioning; I just want the reference in place so that the build process copies the .DLL to the output directory automatically.  I'm actively developing both pieces, so it's a pain to have to manually copy the native DLL every time.

I've added a post-build step to the native DLL project to copy the dll into the AppX folder of the UWP's output directory, which is where it seems to need to live, but that feels like a very brittle solution that the IDE ought to handle on its own much more elegantly.  Not to mention if I blow away the UWP output directory, the native build step fails because the AppX folder doesn't exist yet.

**What's the right way to set up a dependency on a native DLL for a UWP app so that "Build Solution" just Does The Right Thing(TM)?**

Aside: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73434005/package-a-native-dll-in-a-uwp-project-visual-studio) but the asker doesn't describe *how* he set up the solution, which is where my question lies.

Further aside: This is a utility for internal use, so I'm not so much worried about limitations of Microsoft Store deployment, etc.

Comment: UWP can directly reference the class library, but it seems that Visual Studio currently does not have a more elegant way to set the dependency on native DLL for UWP app. Adding it to the AppX folder after building(post-build step) is a good workaround for now.